# How set Button Visibility according to selected row in Datagridview?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview

Hi  i am developing a data grid to show  data using WPF MVVM. i need to add delete button when single row select by user.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn  Width="10*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Visibility="Collapsed"  Width="20" cal:Message.Attach="DeleteRow($dataContext)">Del</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I need to set visibility true of the button only selected row. I cannot use code behind because this is in MVVM architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is a simple approach

you need a converter in your resources

eg

```
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter" />
```

button's visibility

```
    <Button Visibility="{Binding IsSelected,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}, 
                                 Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```